Why are left Bousfield localisations of (left proper, combinatorial) simplicial model categories simplicial?
Let $\mathsf{M}$ be a simplicial model category and let $S$ be a set of morphisms of $\mathsf{M}$. I was trying to understand one of the arguments of the proof of Proposition A.3.7.3 of Higher topos theory, where it is asserted that if $\mathsf{M}$ is combinatorial and left proper, then the left Bousfield localisation $\mathrm{L}_S\mathsf{M}$ of $\mathsf{M}$ with respect to $S$ exists and is a combinatorial, left proper simplicial model category (whose fibrant objects are well-understood). I am specifically trying to understand why $\mathrm{L}_S\mathsf{M}$ is a simplicial model category.
Proposition A.3.1.7 of HTT provides necessary and sufficient conditions for a category with a simplicial action (a simplicial enrichment and a (co)tensoring over the category of simplicial sets) and a model structure to be a simplicial model category, provided that every object of the category is cofibrant in the ambient model structure. However, unless I am mistaken, in Proposition A.3.7.3, it is not assumed that every object is cofibrant (indeed, Proposition A.3.7.3 is an existence result for left proper (combinatorial simplicial) model categories, and left properness would be a redundant asumption if it were assumed that every object is cofibrant). Thus I do not understand why Proposition A.3.1.7 can be applied in the proof of Proposition A.3.7.3 to establish that $\mathrm{L}_S\mathsf{M}$ is a simplicial model category.
Thanks in advance for any insight!

Any left Bousfield localization of a simplicial model category is simplicial by Part (4) of Theorem 4.1.1 in Hirschhorn's Model Categories and Their Localizations.

Thank you very much! I should have looked in Hirschhorn's book where the corresponding theorem is proved.
